# php printf 5 digit but show extra 1 digit

Tags: laravel-5.4, php-7

I found a problem about `printf('%50d',33)` As title, 
I just want it to show 00033, but it shows 000335.

i try `printf('%50d-',33)` it become `00033-6`, 
if not wrong last number is total digit count.

May I know how to remove that?

> **EDITED**

**Model/Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['code'];
    public function getCodeAttribute(){
        return $this->attributes['code'] = sprintf("A%'.05d",$this->id);
    }
}
```

**View/home.blade.php**

```html
<ul class='codeList'>
  @foreach($products as $product)
  <li>
  <div class='name'>{{ $product->name }}</div>
  <div class='code'>{{ $product->code }}</div> {{-- This Part Show A00033 --}}
  </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to specify the components of the format string *in the right order*, [as specified in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: @MattGibson thanks for your reply, i accidentally copy wrong code.
because in my source is printf("A%'.05d",$this->id) so is typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
use `sprintf("A%'.05d",$this->id);` instent of `printf("A%'.05d",$this->id);`

Thanks @Matt for the link.
Update Answer to question post.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your format string is not in the right order as [mentioned](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300836/matt-gibson).
Should be `printf("%'.05d\n",33);`

Comment: thanks for try to help.
that is my typo actually in my source is show printf('A%05d',$this->id);
and i did try printf("%'.05d\n",$this->id); it same extra one number at last.